# Scala : Nested getOrElse

Tags: scala, scala-option

I would like to create a method that takes as arguments an array of options and a default value and return the first non empty option otherwise the default value :

```
def customGetOrElse[T](options : Array[Option[T]], defaultValue : T) : T = {
  // Example if options contain 2 elements
  options(0).getOrElse(options(1).getOrElse(defaultValue))
  // If options contain 3 elements
  options(0).getOrElse(options(1).getOrElse(options(2).getOrElse(defaultValue)))
}
```

But I am struggling to make this method working for any size of the array. Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def customGetOrElse[T](options : Array[Option[T]], defaultValue : T) : T = {
  options.find(_.isDefined).flatten.getOrElse(defaultValue)
}
```

Comment: Of course ! I was focused on nesting getOrElse I completely forgot about using find. Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

The one with `collectFirst`

```
def customGetOrElse[T](options: Array[Option[T]], defaultValue: T): T =
 options.collectFirst { case Some(value) => value }.getOrElse(defaultValue)
```

## Scala REPL

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.6 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_162).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)


 def customGetOrElse[T](options: Array[Option[T]], defaultValue: T): T =
  options.collectFirst { case Some(value) => value }.getOrElse(defaultValue)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

customGetOrElse: [T](options: Array[Option[T]], defaultValue: T)T

scala> customGetOrElse[Int](Array(None, Some(1)), 2)
res0: Int = 1

scala> customGetOrElse[Int](Array(None, None), 2)
res1: Int = 2
```

Comment: Why do you want to fold the whole `Array` even after finding `Some[T]` at the begining ?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh ur right! edited the answer. `collectFirst` is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Use `flatten` over the `options` to reduce `options` to those that have a value. Then use `headOption` to return an `Option` containing the first value present or `None`. Lastly, get the value `T` from the `Option` or return the `defaultValue`.

```
def customGetOrElse[T](options : Array[Option[T]], defaultValue : T) : T = {
  options.flatten.headOption.getOrElse(defaultValue)
}
```

Examples:

```
scala> customGetOrElse[Int](Array(None, None), 666)
res29: Int = 666

scala> customGetOrElse[Int](Array(None, Some(42)), 666)
res30: Int = 42
```

Comment: Why flatten the whole Array ? The non-empty option might be the first or second one, that flatten operation itself will be O(n).

Comment: Good call. Was just thinking about getting the proper shape of things and not performance.